# Bitmap not posting(share) in facebook in android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am share to bitmap  into facebook all are working fine when app is installed in mydevice.problem when app is not in installed in device.Why this happen i didn't understand.I am using HelloFacebookSample.Java

and i am adding following code Into Manifest.xml file

```
<activity
            android:name=".HelloFacebookSampleActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"/>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
  <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
   <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProviderXXXXX92272288220"
                  android:name="com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider"
                  android:exported="true"/>
```

and am adding all permissions also.I am research alot i didn't findout mistake where i done.Advance thanks to all .Sorry ,to my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

When the app is not installed, you can do one of two things:

1. fallback to a web dialog, but there's no support for sharing a bitmap via a web dialog, so you can only share a link.
2. Ask for the publish_actions permission, and upload the photo via the Graph API (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Request/#newUploadPhotoRequest).

You should always wrap your FacebookDialog calls with a canPresentShareDialog check. See the sample code https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share or in the HelloFacebookSample. It will tell you if the share dialog feature is available (if the app is installed and it's of the right version), and you can decide the proper fallback technique to use.